# how to make a judgement about a Chinese character

Tags: qt

like the title,how to make a judgement about a Chinese character ?
for example:
there is a object of QString which consist of some Chinese characters, like "fheuhieu汉字hdfueu".

Comment: What kind of judgment do you want to make? It's hard to answer without knowing that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
String.valueOf(chars[i]).matches("[\\u4E00-\\u9FA5]+")
```

if return true it's a Chinese character

Comment: can you give a simple example about QString's judgement

Comment: .*[\\u4E00-\\u9FA5]+.*   the Regular expression, if contain Chinese character it will matches

Comment: ...thx for telling me this, I use "u" in my project and it works, I suppose "u" stands for Unicode, what's your encoding

Comment: This does not work with Chinese characters outside BMP.